# Qt Creator C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I try to build a programm in Qt Creator (Qt5.7.0) on Windows 10 but I get

> D:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:45: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory

error message. I found out that it may be caused by lack of Windows SDK but I installed it, ran `vcvarsall.bat` and nothing happened. I try to use "MinGW 5.3.0 32-bit" compiler and "GNU gdb 7.10.1 for MinGW 5.3.0 32-bit" debugger (using "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler" doesn't work as well). Any ideas?

Comment: ***run vcvarsall.bat and nothing happened.*** The environment this creates is only good for the `cmd.exe` instance that you ran `vcvarsall.bat` in. Meaning this can not fix `QtCreator` unless you ran it from the same cmd.exe console that you ran `vcvarsall.bat` in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when you compile your project under Qt Creator, you're using a particular kit, tied to a particular installed Qt version. Make sure that the configuration of that kit and that Qt version in Qt Creator has the right compiler selected. C++ code is generally not binary compatible across compilers, so if you've installed a Qt version for say MSVC2012, it'll only work with that compiler and no other. If you're not building Qt yourself, the Qt version you installed must match the compiler you're using it with. Mixing MSVC versions or using a MSVC-built Qt with mingw gcc won't work.

You can have multiple installations of Qt side by side, and each installation can use a different Qt version and/or compiler. You need to let Qt Creator know about them by adding them to the Qt Versions control pane, and then setting up the kits that use these Qt versions.

There's no point to running `vcvars` yourself, since it only sets the environment variables for that particular instance of the command processor. It has no effect on Qt Creator. Qt Creator's build system automatically invokes `vcvars` to set up an environment that the build is executed in.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting content of the "c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\QtProject" folder worked for this error in my case again:

[Qt Creator 4.0.1 (Qt 5.6.2 MSVC2015 32bit) stopped accepting toolchains/compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045966/3096593)

update: my suggested solution worked only sometime, other solution was restarting computer and now neither works. Accepted answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error when had the "bin" directory of MSVC 2012 in my system path variable while trying to use another version of MSVC. Removing the directory from "path" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For building a Qt 5.6 code base, what resolved this build issue for me is setting the "environment" in the kit.

[image: The Kit environment is specified by pressing the "Change" button to the right of "Environment"]

This is the environment text I use:

```
INCLUDE=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_HEADERS}
LIB=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_LIBS}
LIBPATH=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_LIBS}
PATH=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_BINS}
```

Comment: My answer is years late, but I just ran into this problem and the first answer prompted me to check the environment setting in the kit. I was surprised that setting the environment within Qt Creator's kit dialog worked considering that it only adds Qt install paths to the environment and the missing file, cstddef is not in the C:Qt\5.6 path, but is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs.