# Qt Creator 4.0.1 (Qt 5.6.2 MSVC2015 32bit) stopped accepting toolchains/compilers

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I was able to build my Qt projects with Qt Creator 4.0.1 (Qt 5.6.2 MSVC2015 32bit) without any problem until it (suddenly) stopped compiling. In the last picture when I assign Qt5.6.2 to msvc14 it says incompatible ABI (2005 vs 2015) which is strange as Visual Studio 2015 is compiler 14.

Not sure what other info I should provide. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Qt Creator is detecting the wrong ABI for your compiler. Under the _"Compilers"_ tab, click on _"Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (x86)"_ and then look at the bottom pane. What does the "Initialization" field say? Is it the same for both the Auto-Detected version and the Manual version?

Comment: initialization field says "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86" for both versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted content of the "c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\QtProject" folder and now Qt Creator seems to be happy again. Some file(s) must have been corrupted. Impressive.

[image]

---

***EDIT 1***

I found out that I "accidentally" lunched older version of the Qt Creator 2.7.0 which changed files in  "c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\QtProject" folder. File **toolchains.xml** was particularly important as that is where (when using Qt Creator 4.0.1 again) ABI confusion came from.

QtCreator 4.0.1 assigns ABI 2015 to MSVC 14.0 in toolchains.xml file

```
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.SupportedAbi">x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-32bit</value>
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.VarsBat">C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat</value>
```

whereas QtCreator 2.7.0 assigns ABI 2005 to MSVC 14.0 in toolchains.xml file (which is wrong)

```
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.SupportedAbi">x86-windows-msvc2005-pe-32bit</value>
   <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.MsvcToolChain.VarsBat">C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat</value>
```

Qt Creator 4.0.1 was/is not able to fix this and therefore deleting content of the folder gives Qt Creator 4.0.1 chance to go from zero to hero, so to speak.